# how to print Lines Between Two Patterns in file using SED or AWK?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a problem to print the selection of a file between 2 lines using exact strings i.e. "###" and not "####"

I have tried to select a part of a text in file but I can't reach to obtain the wanted selection

by running the command:

> sed -ne "/MULTIPLE-RESOURCES/,/###/p" kubernetes_commands.md

```
### MULTIPLE-RESOURCES

#### Viewing Resource Information

> kubectl get svc, po
> kubectl get deploy, no
> kubectl get all
> kubectl get all --all-namespaces

## KUBECTL

###

> kubectl run -i --tty busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
```

from this text, I expect to have:

```
### MULTIPLE-RESOURCES

#### Viewing Resource Information

> kubectl get svc, po
> kubectl get deploy, no
> kubectl get all
> kubectl get all --all-namespaces

## KUBECTL
```

but the actual result is:

```
### MULTIPLE-RESOURCES

#### Viewing Resource Information
```

Comment: Have you tried anchoring your search pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```
sed -n '/MULTIPLE-RESOURCES/,/^###$/ { /###$/!p; }' file
```

```
### MULTIPLE-RESOURCES

#### Viewing Resource Information

> kubectl get svc, po
> kubectl get deploy, no
> kubectl get all
> kubectl get all --all-namespaces

## KUBECTL
```

Comment: After checking deeper, I can see that with your command, it prints until the last occurence of ###, and not the first occurence. what do I need to modify to print until the first occurence?

Comment: I have created a demo here: https://ideone.com/xGcLWx I included 2 lines of `###` in input but `sed` command is finding only first occurrence of `###`. If your input is different from my demo then I suggest you edit question and paste an input that can reproduce the problem and then I will surely tweak my command.

Comment: based on the example given, you are right. I would like now to stop at the first occurrence that starts with '###' e.g. '### STORAGE-CLASS'.

Comment: Are you going to update your question because I still don't see `STORAGE-CLASS` anywhere. You can see in demo link that it is matching till first occurrence of `###`.

Comment: here is the example that refers the problem above https://justpaste.it/7gjvb. I want to stop to print after the first occurence beginning by '### '. I expect to get: https://justpaste.it/7ckrz as result

Comment: ok try `sed -En '/MULTIPLE-RESOURCES/,/^###([[:blank:]]|$)/ { /^###([[:blank:]]|$)/!p; }' file` Reason why given command wasn't working because now you have more text after `###` in a line but your example has just `###` in a line.

Comment: almost perfect. the first line "### MULTIPLE-RESOURCES" is also removed. it must appear

Comment: Hmm in that case `sed -En '/MULTIPLE-RESOURCES/,/^###([[:blank:]]|$)/p' file | sed '$d'` will better since both start and end lines start with `###` now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a straightforward solution using perl:

```sh
perl -ne 'print if /MULTIPLE-RESOURCES/ .. s/^###\n//'
```

The main point is anchoring the `###` pattern to the beginning (`^`) and end (`\n`) of the line. Replacing it by nothing also ensures that the final `###` line is not printed itself.

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is:

```
sed -n '/MULTI/,/^## KUBE/p' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^### |^###$/{if(++count==1){found=1} else {found=""}} found' Input_file
```

Comment: @Maurice Amar, Could you please check if this helps you too?